# Why am I unable to pull in this submodule from a git repository?

Tags: git, github

There are two repos on Github. `Repo1` and `Module1`

I have previously cloned both of these repos to my local windows machine with Github Desktop and the two repos exist in the following two folders:

- `C:\Users\Me\Documents\GitHub\Repo1`
- `C:\Users\Me\Documents\GitHub\Module1`

Now, someone has added `Module1` as a submodule of `Repo1` and when I look at Github online I see `Module1` exists under `Repo1\submodules`.

If I go to a command line and I run the following command within the `Repo1` folder, `git submodule update --init`, then I get a couple of errors. First, from the `git` CLI, I see the output:

```
Submodule 'submodules/Module1' (https://github.com/MyOrg/Module1.git) registered for path 'submodules/Module1'
fatal: not a git repository: C:/Users/Me/Documents/GitHub/Repo1/submodules/Module1/../../.git/modules/submodules/Module1
Failed to clone 'submodules/Module1'. Retry scheduled
BUG: submodule considered for cloning, doesn't need cloning any more?
fatal: could not get a repository handle for submodule 'submodules/Module1'
```

And in Github Desktop it starts saying:

```
Can't find "Repo1"
It was last seen at C:\Users\Me\Documents\GitHub\Repo1
```

After doing this, there is a new file `C:\Users\Me\Documents\GitHub\Repo1\submodules\Module1\.git` on my local machine that contains the following contents:

`gitdir: ../../.git/modules/submodules/Module1`

And if I delete that file Github Desktop will start recognizing the repo again. But, trying to fetch the repo does not bring in the submodule `Module1`. I end up with an empty `C:\Users\Me\Documents\GitHub\Repo1\submodules\Module1` folder on my local machine.

This makes me think that when the submodule was added from a different architecture (Linux / Mac), and somehow a path was hardcoded in and it's looking in the wrong place. But, I'm not really sure how this submodule functionality works and I'm not sure where to go from here. I need Github Desktop or the Git CLI to pull in the submodule with the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do check that the remote `Repo1` GitHub repository does reference correctly `Module1` in a `.gitmodules` file.
You should see in it:

```
[submodule "Module1"]
        path = submodules/Module1
        url = https://github.com/aUser/Module1
```

Second, try for testing to clone `Repo1` again, in a different folder, using the [`clone --recurse-submodules` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---recurse-submodulesltpathspecgt):

```
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/aUser/Repo1
```

Then open GitHub Desktop, and reference that new `Repo1` clone.
Check that `Module1` is properly imported there.

Comment: Cloning to another folder seems to work. I would rather understand why it broke. But this did solve the problem.